# Mapping Multiple Variables - MapInfo Professional

Tags: mapinfo

I am a fairly new user of MapInfo and was trying to determine if there is a simple way to do the following:

I have these first two parts down:

1. Plot a list of retail stores within a given geographical area.
2. Using a thematic map to "value" a particular zip code based on sales coming in from a particular zip code.

This is the part I am having trouble with:

1. Add an additional layer that will "shade" or "fill" a particular zip code that I have designated for "purchase." Basically I want to be able to shade a zip code and the shading will appear over the thematic shading.. Is this possible?

I have had trouble trying to find anything in the guide/online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/c5f0c7263940a53d8525669b00568e6b/37d6d35058f1d43d852572d6005151a8?OpenDocument

Comment: @Kitex, that's not a comment - that the answer

Answer (score 1):

When creating a thematic you can choose to only use for example the pattern of the style for your thematic. If you have another thematic for the same layer, MapInfo will merge the pattern with the colour from the other thematic.
You can set which part of the style to use thru the Styles button in step 3 of creating the thematic map.

Try searching the help system in MI Pro for Bivariate.